# Is there any way of converting time from "hh:mm:ss" format to "hh:mm AM/PM" format?

Tags: java, android, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I am storing time in the database in this format: `"hh:mm:ss"` (example- 09:30:00) and then retrieving and trying to show it to users in this format: "hh:mm AM/PM" (example- 09:30 AM).

I'm using below code for converting it:

```
DateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
String startTimeInSF = currentTime.format(startTime);
String endTimeInSF = currentTime.format(endTime);
```

where `startTime` and `endTime` is in `hh:mm:ss` format, but the above code is producing this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String`.

Please let me know how can I successfully convert the time from `hh:mm:ss` to `hh:mm AM/PM`?

Comment: Try this "hh:mm tt"

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ failed! produced this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 't'`

Comment: You need one `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your date from its original format, and another `SimpleDateFormat` to format the result into a new format.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should parse your "hh:mm:ss" time into a Date Object, then use formatter to format it to "hh:mm a".

Like this :

```
    DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format1.parse("01:11:22");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String result = format2.format(date);
        return result;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the parse(String source) method. The format() methods take in a Date object and output a String representation of the object. the parse methods take in a String object and converts it to a Date object.

To do what you want, you'll need to have a DateFormat with hh:mm:ss, convert the database String to a Date using parse, and then use your existing DateFormat and use format on the Date object to get the output String to display to your user.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code something like this, format function will not work directly on String object that is root cause of your exception.

```
DateFormat inputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat"HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = inputFormatter1.parse("22:10:11");

        DateFormat outputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String output1 = outputFormatter1.format(date1); //
```

Out will be 10:10 pm